# How to set nat_gateway_id in aws_route_table

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

main.tf

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../modules/aws/vpc"

  env_prefix  = "prod"
  environment = "production"
  env_name    = "test"
  vpc_cidr    = "10.1.0.0/16"

  public_subnet_cidrs = {
    test-prod-nat = {
      subnet = "10.1.15.0/24"
      name   = "test-prod-nat"
      az     = "ap-northeast-1a"
    }
  }
}
```

nat.tf

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "private" {
  for_each = var.public_subnet_cidrs

  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gateway.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s_%s", var.env_prefix, var.env_name, "nat-gateway")
    }
  )

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

route_table.tf

```
/**
 * for private subnet
 */
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dandori.id

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s", var.env_prefix, var.env_name)
    }
  )

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = [
      for v in aws_nat_gateway.private : v.id
    ]
  }
  
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

When I run the **terraform plan** after creating the above tf file, I get the following Error

**【Error】**

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on ../modules/aws/vpc/route_table.tf line 55, in resource "aws_route_table" "private":
│   55:     nat_gateway_id = [
│   56:       for v in aws_nat_gateway.private : v.id
│   57:     ]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_nat_gateway.private is object with 1 attribute "test-prod-nat"
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "nat_gateway_id": string required.
```

route_table.tf and nat.tf will be files in the module
I'm trying to set the nat_gateway_id in route_table.tf using the for loop method, but I can't set it correctly as shown in the Error message.

What should I do to solve this problem?
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a route table for each `aws_nat_gateway.private`, then it should be:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {


  for_each = aws_nat_gateway.private


  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dandori.id

  tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      Name = format("%s_%s", var.env_prefix, var.env_name)
    }
  )

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = each.value["id"]
  }
  
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was able to solve the problem.

Is it not possible to set the nat_gateway_id with the following statement that I was setting for nat_gateway_id

`nat_gateway_id = [
      for v in aws_nat_gateway.private : v.id   
 ]`